# Brezis 5.28.2 About the competition of an orthogonal sequence

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, hamel-basis

Let $(e_n)$  be an orthonormal sequence in $H$ is parable. Prove that there exists an orthonormal basis of $H$ that contains $\bigcup_{n\geq 1} \{e_n\}$

My try:

Define the set $\Omega$ as follows:

$$\Omega = \{X \subseteq H : \{e_1\} \subseteq X \text{ and } X \text{ is an orthonormal sequence of } H\}$$

Now, we can proceed with the proof:

1. **Define the Partial Order**: Let the partial order on $\Omega$ be set inclusion, i.e., $X \leq Y$ if $X \subseteq Y$ for $X, Y \in \Omega$.
2. **Show Non-Emptyness**: Prove that $\Omega$ is non-empty. This follows from Hipotesis.
3. **Show Chains Have Upper Bounds**: Take an arbitrary chain $\mathcal{C}$ in $\Omega$, and consider the union of all sets in this chain, i.e., $\bigcup \mathcal{C}$ is an orthonormal sequence size is partial ordened and $e_1$ is on all elements.
4. **Apply Zorn's Lemma**: By Zorn's lemma, there exists a maximal element $M$ in $\Omega$.
5. **Show $M$ is a Basis of $H$**: Do by contradicción.
6. **Prove $M$ Contains the Given Sequence**: Since $\{e_1\} \subseteq M$ (as per the definition of $\Omega$), and $M$ is maximal, it follows that $M$ contains the sequence $\{e_n\}$.

is fine ?